# How to use (Is there) code completion without using vue-cli

Tags: vue.js, vuejs2, sublimetext3, sublime-text-plugin

i try to do my first steps with vue.js.

My Question is:
Is there a possibility for the use of code completion if i dont wat to use the cli.
Therefore i have no .vue-Files.

I just use vue by binding the script (vue.js) over the < script>-tag to my html code.
I created a new javaScript-File (myVue.js) and also include it per script-tag in my html.
Vue itself is working correctly!

My problem is that the plugins i found so far (for sublime etc.) are not working with the .js-files.

Is there a way to use code completion and (correct) syntaxhighlighting in .js-files?

---

Thanks for having me.

Comment: why are you doing this way? do you like sending vue compiler in httpresponse ?

Comment: one thing is that i want to have full access to thejavascript possibilities to collect components dynamically after page loading and mater have the chance to manipulate. (also i have no rigths to install the cli on my machine)
---- i dont understand your second question. could you be a bit mor specific by that

Comment: if you are using js version of vuejs library,the vuejs library will have vue compiler in itself. THis compiler will compile&render your vuejs code in browser. This is not a good way to build real time live apps. The vuecli compiles and outputs only necessary js content for our usage. Compiler is removed.

Comment: @divine is there a bigger disadvantage about this

Comment: project management is easy if you use vue-cli. if you are just playing around then anything is fine